Problem accessing shadow root elements in selenium
I am working with Selenium. Don't have much experience and would appreciate some help.
The problem: I have HTML page. There is an element with tag .
The  is a Web Component that uses Shadow DOM. Under it, in the HTML I see "#shadow-root (open)". When in selenium I write this:
elem = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@id="app"]/div/klyme-widget')
print(driver.execute_script('return arguments[0].innerHTML', elem))
nothing is returned. How to get to HTML elements inside . I would like to click a button that is inside this shadow DOM with XPATH "//button[normalize-space(text())='Select Your Bank']"
I have already tried the following, but it throws error "invalid argument: invalid locator":
Use JavaScript to access the shadow root
shadow_root = driver.execute_script('return arguments[0].shadowRoot', host_element)
Now find the button inside the shadow root
button = shadow_root.find_element(By.XPATH, "//button[normalize-space(text())='Select Your Bank']")
button.click()
I was expecting that the button would be found and clickable.

There are 369 Stack Overflow answers marked shadow dom and selenium : https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=%5bshadow-dom%5d%20selenium&searchOn=3
